# Base table or view not found when using routes

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have an issue with the admin side of a site I'm doing. I have included on the admin side 4 links but when I click on any of them I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sonic.admins' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `admins` where `id` = peripherals limit 1)

I have no idea where that SQL query is coming from as I am not running any to my knowledge

I'm using the following controller as an example of one broken link:

```
Route::resource('/admin/games', 'AdminGamesController', ['names'=>[
  'index'=>'games.index',
  'create'=>'games.create',
  'store'=>'games.store',
  'edit'=>'games.edit',
  'show'=>'games.show',
  'destroy'=>'games.destroy',
  ]]);
```

but

```
Route::resource('/admin', 'AdminController', ['names'=>[
  'index'=>'admin.index',
  'create'=>'admin.create',
  'store'=>'admin.store',
  'edit'=>'admin.edit',
  'show'=>'admin.show',
  'destroy'=>'admin.destroy',
  ]]);
```

works fine.

Here is the controller I'm using for the example routing above:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminGamesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return 'test';
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

here's the links

```
<div class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <a href="{{route('home.index')}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
  <a href="{{route('games.index')}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Games</a>
  <a href="{{route('figures.index')}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Figures</a>
  <a href="{{route('guides.index')}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Guides</a>
  <a href="{{route('peripherals.index')}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Peripherals</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the issue is coming from one of your auth / guest check middleware.

Comment: I removed the middleware but it's still doing it

Comment: look for stack trace in storage/logs/ to see where it's happening from.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious in there

Comment: Maybe some helper inside the view / layout?

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM : Routes are clashing/overlapping each other**

```
admin/{admin}  // This is admin route URL
admin/games    // and this is from admin games route URL

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admins',  // Here we need to do something different
    'as'     => 'admin.'
],function () {
    Route::resource('admin','AdminController');
});
// http://localhost/project_name/public/admins/admin
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'as'     => 'admin.'
],function () {
    Route::resource('games','AdminGamesController');
});

// http://localhost/awsupload/public/admin/games
```

Here is what I've tried in my route ONLY for admin games and it's working fine

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'as'     => 'admin.'
],function () {
    Route::resource('games','AdminGamesController');
});
```

[image]

In blade file, games routes are accessable by the follwing blade syntax :

```
    // Games Listing
    {{route('admin.games.index')}}

    // Save game to the database
    {{route('admin.games.store')}}

    // Create Game form/page
    {{route('admin.games.create')}}

    // Show single game details
    {{route('admin.games.show',['game_id'])}}

    // Show edit form for single game
    {{route('admin.games.edit',['game_id'])}}

    // Update single game details
    {{route('admin.games.update',['game_id'])}}

    // Remove/Delete single game
    {{route('admin.games.destroy',['game_id'])}}
```